# Manipulating single cell in a google spreadsheet

Tags: java, google-data-api

So for an application that I am writing for a friend of mine, I needed to interact with the google drive and google data api in order to create folders and manipulate data in a google spreadsheet.

Now looking at the API beforehand it all seemed pretty straightforward.
Until you actually make a start and figure out that every piece of documentation you could possibly find on the internet is pretty much deprecated.

Eventually I figured out most parts after some time on the internet (Like authentication and creating new folders / copying files etc.)
so far so good.

But now I have come at the following problem:
I am trying to manipulate a single cell (Well actually multiple but 1 by 1) and after 2 days of going through google's atrocious documentation I have turned to you guys.

I have come as far as authenticating my user and even reading the values from the spreadsheet however I can't seem to write to it.

```
CellEntry newEntry = new CellEntry(row,col, "value");
service.insert(cellFeedUrl, newEntry);
System.out.println("Added!");
```

This is what I got from their code sample, however the service.insert() returns an error

```
 Exception in thread "main" com.google.gdata.util.ServiceException: Internal Server Error
Internal Error

at com.google.gdata.client.http.HttpGDataRequest.handleErrorResponse(HttpGDataRequest.java:632)
at com.google.gdata.client.http.GoogleGDataRequest.handleErrorResponse(GoogleGDataRequest.java:564)
at com.google.gdata.client.http.HttpGDataRequest.checkResponse(HttpGDataRequest.java:560)
at com.google.gdata.client.http.HttpGDataRequest.execute(HttpGDataRequest.java:538)
at com.google.gdata.client.http.GoogleGDataRequest.execute(GoogleGDataRequest.java:536)
at com.google.gdata.client.Service.insert(Service.java:1409)
at com.google.gdata.client.GoogleService.insert(GoogleService.java:613)
```

I really hope someone here can help me out, I am pretty desperate and google has not been my friend on this one (Neither has google's own documentation)

- A.E.

Comment: I can attest to the statements that Google's API docs are **often** incomplete or just flat out wrong.  One "trick" is to try and use the python versions that you can actually read the code for and try to build from there.

Comment: Why did you use the Google-Apps-Script tag.?  Not relevant at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out myself,

As I already said in one of the comments I passed a value of 0 to variable col, passing that to the google server gave me an error back.

Changing the loop that was calling:

```
 new CellEntry(row,col, "value");
```

To start at 1 instead of 0 fixed it.

- AE

Comment: Thanks! Took me 2 hours to figure out that Internal Server Error actually means: "GOOGLE SPREADSHEETS IS NOT ZERO-BASED" :).